Theorem 1.2.8 in $C^*$-algebras and operator theory - Gerald J. Murphy
Recall that if $K$ is a non-empty compact set in $\mathbb{C}$, its complement $\mathbb{C}\setminus{K}$ admits exactly one unbounded component, and that the bounded components of $\mathbb{C}\setminus{K}$ are called the holes of $K$.
Theorem 1.2.8 (in $C^*$-algebras and operator theory by Gerald J. Murphy): Let $B$ be a closed unital subalgebra of a unital Banach algebra $A$.

The set $\mathrm{Inv}(B)$ is a clopen subset of $B \cap \mathrm{Inv}(A)$.

For each $b \in B$, $\sigma_A(b) \subseteq \sigma_B(b)$ and $\partial{\sigma_B(b)} \subseteq \partial{\sigma_A(b)}$.

If $b \in B$ and $\sigma_A(b)$ has no holes, then $\sigma_A(b) =\sigma_B(b)$.


I have a question about this theorem.
Whether $\text{conv}({\sigma_A(b)})=\text{conv}({\sigma_B(b)})$ is true?

Please provide a full problem statement, we don't all have the book on hand.

Thx for your advice. I've written out the whole theorem

Yes, this is true. Hint: show that for a nonempty compact $K$, $\text{conv}(\partial K) = \text{conv}(K)$.

Thank you for your answer.  Can you provide the proof process?

The hint given by David Gao is very instructive. Since OP asks for details, I will elaborate on that.
By (2) in your list, for $b\in B \subset A$ we know that $\sigma_A(b) \subset \sigma_B(b)$ and that $\partial\sigma_B(b) \subset \partial\sigma_A(b)$. It follows that $\mathrm{conv}(\sigma_A(b)) \subset \mathrm{conv}(\sigma_B(b))$ and that $\mathrm{conv}(\partial\sigma_B(b)) \subset \mathrm{conv}(\partial\sigma_A(b))$.
So, if we show that for a compact set $K \subset \mathbb{C}$ we have $\mathrm{conv}(\partial K) = \mathrm{conv}(K)$, the second inclusion mentioned above will be precisely saying that $\mathrm{conv}(\sigma_B(b)) \subset \mathrm{conv}(\sigma_A(b))$. Combined with the first inclusion above, we will obtain $\mathrm{conv}(\sigma_B(b)) = \mathrm{conv}(\sigma_A(b))$.
Let $K \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a compact set. Since $\partial K \subset K$, the inclusion $\mathrm{conv}(\partial K ) \subset \mathrm{conv}(K)$ is obvious. Now let us show the reverse inclusion, so let $z,w\in K$ be two points and let $ t\in[0,1]$. We wish to show that $tz+(1-t)w \in \mathrm{conv}(\partial K)$.
We assume that $z,w$ are distinct points.
Let $L_{z,w} \subset \mathbb{C}$ denote the line in the complex plane that passes through the points $z$ and $w$, which we can parametrize as $L = \{\lambda z +(1-\lambda)w : \lambda\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Since $K$ is compact, it is bounded, and thus if
$$\alpha_1:=\inf\{\lambda\in\mathbb{R}: \lambda z+(1-\lambda)w\in K\}$$
$$\alpha_2:=\sup\{\lambda\in\mathbb{R}: \lambda z+(1-\lambda)w\in K\},$$
we must have $-\infty<\alpha_1\le\alpha_2<+\infty$. Moreover, since for $\lambda =0$ we have $\lambda z +(1-\lambda)w=w\in K$, we must have $\alpha_1\le 0$ and since for $\lambda =1$ we have $\lambda z +(1-\lambda)w = z\in K$, we must have $1\le \alpha_2$.
Also, the points $\alpha_i z+(1-\alpha_i)w$ ($i=1,2$) both lie in the boundary of $K$; indeed, they both lie in $K$ by their definition and since $K$ is closed. At the same time, for any $\varepsilon>0$ the point $(\alpha_1-\varepsilon)z+(1-(\alpha_1-\varepsilon))w$ does not lie in $K$, but as $\varepsilon\to0^+$, this approximates $\alpha_1z+(1-\alpha_1)w$, and one argues similarly to see that $\alpha_2z+(1-\alpha_2)w\in \partial K$.
Now simply note that
$$t z+ (1-t) w = \frac{t-\alpha_2}{\alpha_1-\alpha_2}(\alpha_1 z + (1-\alpha_1)w) + (1-\frac{t-\alpha_2}{\alpha_1-\alpha_2})(\alpha_2 z + (1-\alpha_2)w)  $$
and that since $\alpha_1\le0 \le t \le 1 \le \alpha_2$, the above is a convex combination of two points in $\partial K$.
Now assume that $z=w$; we wish to show that $z=w\in\mathrm{conv}(\partial K)$. If $z=w$ already lies in $\partial K$, there is nothing to show. Otherwise, pick a point $p\in\partial K$ (the boundary is non-empty, since $\mathbb{C}$ is connected). Now the points $p$ and $z=w$ are two distinct points in $K$, and in our earlier work we already showed that the segment $\{t z +(1-t)p: t\in [0,1]\}$ lies inside $\mathrm{conv}(\partial K)$. In particular, for $t=1$ we get that $z\in\mathrm{conv}(\partial K)$.

Thank you for your solution. I have benefited a lot.
